# how does destructuring array get length property

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I came across this destructuring expression in an article.

```
const words = ['oops', 'gasp', 'shout', 'sun'];
let { length } = words;
console.log(length); // 4
```

How does `length` get the value of 4? I know `.length` is a property of the array, but how does this syntax work? It seems to be doing `let length = words.length;` and in fact in babel does output it as such. But my question is what is the logic behind it? 
What is confusing me is the mix of an array of values and the the use of `{length}`.

I have read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) 's description but can't see this example explained.

Comment: you're destructuring an OBJECT {} ... an Array is an Object too ... so ... hurrah for ES2015+

Comment: `{ length } = someobject` is telling the processor to create a variable named `length` with a value that is stored in the property named `length` of the object on the right hand side. Same works if you do `{ kat } = { kat:3 }`

Comment: really, the babel output should be enough to know what's going on - there's nothing mysterious about it (except for the new syntax of course)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think of the code as being

```
const words = {0:'oops', 1:'gasp', 2:'shout', 3:'sun', length:4};
let { length } = words;
console.log(length);
```

Which it essentially is (nevermind all the other stuff arrays come with)

Does it make sense now?

Comment: So is my words array being coerced to an Object with the length property?

Comment: no ... not quite ... everything (that isn't a primitive) in javascript inherits from Object - look at the prototype chain for an array

Comment: coercion would be, for example `words+''` ... outputs the **coerced to string** `"oops,gasp,shout,sun"`

Comment: Yes, it makes sense but why they making a complex structure as like this what would be the evolving purpose of this type of structure any personal suggestion or experience.

Answer (score 15):

### Intro

I had the same question so I read the docs and it finally clicked for me that the variable (`length`) is just being assigned the Object’s value at the key with the same name as the variable (`words[length]`).

That may not make sense, so I’m going to start by explaining this type of destructuring in 2 steps and then show how it applies in this situation.

I’ll then provide one last (cool) example which confused me initially and led me to research this topic. It’s also the exact problem described in a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087877/javascript-arrow-function-with-object-as-parameter).

---

### Destructuring

This syntax is called [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) (MDN):

```
let a, b;

({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2});
a; // 1
b; // 2


({b, a} = {c: 3, b: 2, d: 4, a: 1});
a; // 1
b; // 2
```

Same result – order doesn't matter!

**The variables on the left (`a` & `b`) are assigned to the value of their corresponding key's value on the Object (right).**

---

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
let {a, b} = obj;

a; // 1
b; // 2
```

We can store the object on the right into a variable (`obj` in this case) and then use the same syntax (without parens).

---

### Applied to your Example (Array)

Finally, let's show the `words` array as an Object (arrays are just Objects under the hood).

Here's what you'll see if you type `['oops', 'gasp', 'shout', 'sun']` into Chrome's console:

[image: chrome console output]

```
const words = {0: 'oops', 1: 'gasp', 2: 'shout', 3: 'sun', length: 4};
let { length } = words;
console.log(length); // 4
```

Just like above, it's going to set the `length` variable (left) to the value of the corresponding key in the `words` Object/array (right). `words[length]` has a value of `4` so the `length` variable (left) now has a value of `4` as well.

---

### Example Where Destructuring is Useful

From [Wes Bos's Blog](http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/):

Given a `person` Object, how do you create global variables referring to its properties?

```
const person = {
  first: 'Wes',
  last: 'Bos',
  country: 'Canada',
  city: 'Hamilton',
  twitter: '@wesbos'
};
```

Old School:

```
const first = person.first;
const last = person.last;
```

The power of destructuring!

```
const { first, last } = person;
```

---

### BONUS: Cool Usage w/ [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description) (MDN)

Challenge: return new array with the lengths of the respective elements in the input array.

This example is shown as a way to use arrow functions. All three solutions solve the problem, they’re just showing the evolution to finally arrive at a simple one-liner.

```
var materials = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

materials.map(function(material) { 
  return material.length; 
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

materials.map((material) => {
  return material.length;
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

materials.map(({length}) => length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

On each iteration of the input array passed to `map`, we are setting the `{length}` parameter to the current element of `materials` that is passed in as an argument:

```
{length} = 'Hydrogen';
```

This sets the `length` variable to the `length` property of the current string element (more on that below) and then simply returns the value of `length` to the `map` function which eventually returns a new array with all of the elements from the original array's lengths as its elements.

### Supplement: String (primitive) vs. Array (Object)

"strings" are "primitives", not objects, so they don't have properties BUT when you try to call a property such as `.length` on a string, the primitive is coerced (changed) into a [String Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Here's what a `String` Object looks like in the Chrome console. Notice how it's practically the same as the `Array` Object. `String` (function) is a constructor, so calling `new` will create a new Object constructed from that function with `String` (Object) as its prototype (which is what `__proto__` refers to):

[image: new String in Chrome console]

Comment: Not sure why someone voted this down! Great explanation a clear. We now understand:)

Comment: Totally more ultra super better..er answer than the one selected as solution!

Comment: Very useful answer. Thanks for taking the time to break this down.

Comment: Thanks. It was very nice explaination.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a property inside the `{` and `}` that belongs to the `Array`, it's value is copied.
Here we check for the property `constructor`. Will log `constructor function` to console.

IF you add a property not belongs to an array, will return `undefined`

Another Example

```js
const words = ['oops', 'gasp', 'shout', 'sun'];
let { constructor } = words;
console.log(constructor);
```

We are testing for `something` will return `undefined`

```js
const words = ['oops', 'gasp', 'shout', 'sun'];
let { something } = words;
console.log(something);
```

Comment: So it is checking the prototype chain for the property `length`. So if I changed it to `nonsense` it would return `undefined`?

Comment: Not sure how the same code with a different property explains it!!

Comment: check the answer now. it is

Comment: `add a property` - there's no properties being added!

Comment: `Will log constructor function to console.` - well, it actually logs `function Array() {
    [native code]
}` in firefox :p

Comment: sorry, I thought you meant it would literally output `constructor function` - my bad

Comment: since it is a native code, the function body shown like that only. You can check it by typing `alert;` will log `function alert() { [native code] }`