# JavaScript arrow function with object as parameter

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Got the piece of code from:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
var materials = [
    'Hydrogen',
    'Helium',
    'Lithium',
    'Beryllium'
];
```

I can understand this:

```
var x = materials.map(function(material) {
    return material.length;
});

console.log(x);
```

Result: `[8, 6, 7, 9]`

Arrow function example:

```
var z = materials.map( ( {length} ) => length );
console.log(z);
```

Result: `[8, 6, 7, 9]`

In the arrow function I don't understand what is going on.

The `length` param of the arrow function callback in `map()` should be the current value (from my understanding of `map()`) yet, `=> length` somehow returns the length of the string, and not the current value.

How is this even possible, what is going on when executing `({length}) => length`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrow functions, you can do the same thing with a traditional function. It's object destructuring.

Comment: @robert-rocha Bottom of my answer (to duplicate question) tackles this precise problem! https://stackoverflow.com/a/48351652/4722345