# Es lint prefer destructuring

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I don't know how I can store the length of an array by using [es6](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) object destructuring:

```
const length = this.props.options.length;
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [/es6-how-to-destructure-from-an-object-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343763/es6-how-to-destructure-from-an-object-with-a-string-key/44343796#44343796)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595907/how-does-destructuring-array-get-length-property it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is like this:

```
const { length } = this.props.options
```